# Android Create image with ArrayList

Tags: android, imageview

I have a very large **ArrayList** with random values ​​e.g from 0 to 200.
Now I want to create an **Image** that each value has an associate pixel.
Moreover, if this value of the array is e.g greater than 100 the pixel will be red, otherwise black.

Comment: what are the dimensions of the image?

Comment: width="80dp" height="80dp", defined in my Layout

Comment: And what is the problem exactly? Or the question? And how do you want to associate a value with which pixel?

Comment: I don't know how to realize it. The first item of the array will be (0,0); the second (0,1) ... Then (1,0), (1,1)

Comment: Is the (1,1) a random value between 0 and 200? With witch pixel should this one be associated?

Comment: No. (1,1) are the coordinates X and Y. I'd like to populate the ArrayList with random numbers and check them. If the first is over 100 the pixel (0,0) will be red. Then I check the second and if it is50 the pixel (0,1) will be black

Comment: You have an array an an arraylist? Where are the values? You should really try to explain what you have.

Comment: See the comment above